# Razer Blade 15 Advanced with Ubuntu 22.04 Touchpad becomes erratic after suspend

Tags: kernel, suspend, touchpad, 22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Mid 2021 Razer Blade 15 Advanced (RZ09-0409).  It seems to work pretty well and I have very few issues (webcam mainly).  There is however a problem that I can't get past.

When I resume from suspending the device the touchpad barely works.  Its erratic and unusable.  I found the following in the logs

```
17:21:34 kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN0406:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65280)
17:21:34 kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN0406:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65280)
17:21:34 kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN0406:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/3583)
17:21:34 kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN0406:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65280)
17:21:34 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_EXIST, While executing method \_WAK (20210730/hwesleep-47)
17:21:34 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_EXIST, While executing method \_WAK (20210730/hwesleep-47)
17:21:34 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_WAK due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
17:21:34 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \RWAK due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
17:21:34 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC0.RTEC due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
17:21:34 kernel: ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20210730/exfldio-261)
17:21:34 kernel: ACPI Error: No handler for Region [VRTC] (00000000236b02ff) [SystemCMOS] (20210730/evregion-130)
```

Any ideas how to get around this.  I have logged a big on Ubuntu but it hasn't moved.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1966546

Comment: Confirm. Just installed the OS on a weak laptop, which is meant to be frequently suspended. Now that it's practically impossible, I can't decide what to do. The bug is really annoying.

Comment: Did either of you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: @master_clown did you find any solution?

Comment: @Kay, no, I'm completely at loss. Moreover, I changed OS to Linux Lite 6.0 (which is based on Ubuntu 22.04 though), the bug still remains

Comment: @master_clown check my answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418408/razer-blade-15-errors-on-new-ubuntu-22-installation-acpi-bios-error-bug-trac

Comment: @Kay, it worked!! It's amazing and I actually cannot believe it! Because of this bug I had to buy a standalone mouse. I thought it's a bug of the kernel (it may be so still), but I'm glad that you found such workaround. Thank you very much! Now I can use my touchpad (it works not only for trackpads, as we see). However, I think you better mark the third step as optional for those, who have nvidia (my laptop has only integrated graphics, and yet it worked).

Comment: @Kay, it looks like it's enough to use s2idle sleep mode only, without creating a service. As it seems, the touchpad problem is related to "deep" sleep mode. Until it's fixed I'll have to use s2idle, however, it will cause more overhead on battery

Comment: @master_clown same, i noitced that when you put the laptop into sleep mode, it doesent really sleep completely. The laptop stays warm, how about yours?

Comment: @Kay, I can't really tell, because my laptop doesn't have a fan, and light indicator doesn't work in linux out-of-the-box. However, the battery now discharges quite fast, so I had to move back to old options. I think either the touchpad driver is messed up, or sleeping mechanism is.