# Razer Blade 15 Errors on new ubuntu 22 installation ACPI BIOS Error (bug) + trackpad not working after suspending

Tags: boot, suspend, 22.04, acpi

I have a razer blade 15 laptop. I have 2 ssd's, one which already has windows 11 installed and a 2nd ssd which i have just finished installed ubuntu 22.

However before ubuntu loads i get some errors that flash up on my screen.

**cat /var/log/dmesg**

```
[    0.315414] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG2.WKEN], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.315419] kernel: fbcon: Taking over console
[    0.315425] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.315430] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG2._DSW], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.315433] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.315435] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315445] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG2._PR0], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.315447] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.315449] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315450] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG2._PR3], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.315452] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.315454] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315562] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG3.WKEN], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.315564] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.315569] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG3._DSW], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.315571] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.315573] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315581] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG3._PR0], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.315584] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.315586] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315587] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG3._PR3], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.315589] kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.315591] kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.320261] kernel: ACPI: 15 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.330857] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.330865] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF94D1402B2800 0001CB (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Psd  00003000 INTL 20191018)
[    0.331638] kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PR00: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked
[    0.333634] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.333639] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF94D141EF0000 000394 (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20191018)
[    0.334552] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.334557] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF94D141F57000 00051E (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20191018)
[    0.335560] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.335565] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF94D141EF0800 00028B (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Hwp  00003000 INTL 20191018)
[    0.336633] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.336639] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF94D14007C000 0008E7 (v02 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20191018)
[    0.337679] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.337683] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF94D141F50000 00048A (v02 PmRef  ApHwp    00003000 INTL 20191018)
[    0.338641] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.338646] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF94D141F51000 0004D4 (v02 PmRef  ApPsd    00003000 INTL 20191018)
[    0.339594] kernel: ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.339599] kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF94D141F52000 00048A (v02 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20191018)
[    0.346569] kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.346569] kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    0.347240] kernel: ACPI Error: No handler for Region [VRTC] (000000006ff28827) [SystemCMOS] (20210730/evregion-130)
[    0.347244] kernel: ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20210730/exfldio-261)
[    0.347247] kernel: 
[    0.347248] kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [RTEC]
[    0.347248] kernel: 
[    0.347249] kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [RTEC]
[    0.347249] kernel: 
[    0.347250] kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC0.RTEC due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.347254] kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC0._REG due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.347258] kernel: ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.347260] kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PC00.LPCB.EC0_: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions
[    0.347260] kernel: ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.347297] kernel: ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.347298] kernel: ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.347330] kernel: PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.349021] kernel: ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
[    0.349523] kernel: ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PG00]
```

Im not sure if its related, but when i restore the laptop after suspending, the trackpad no longer works.

I think these are the errors that flash up on restoring after suspension

```
[    0.347240] kernel: ACPI Error: No handler for Region [VRTC] (000000006ff28827) [SystemCMOS] (20210730/evregion-130)
[    0.347244] kernel: ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20210730/exfldio-261)
[    0.347247] kernel: 
[    0.347248] kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [RTEC]
[    0.347248] kernel: 
[    0.347249] kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [RTEC]
[    0.347249] kernel: 
[    0.347250] kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC0.RTEC due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.347254] kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC0._REG due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.347258] kernel: ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.347260] kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PC00.LPCB.EC0_: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions
[    0.347260] kernel: ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.347297] kernel: ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.347298] kernel: ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.347330] kernel: PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.349021] kernel: ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
```

Comment: Having the same issue but everything seems to be working…I also just installed version 22.04…I guess it something to do with the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @MichaelCollins not sure, have you tried ubuntu 20?

Comment: I just tried with ubuntu 20, same issue

Comment: I also updated the bios to the latest version 2.02 (released in january). But that did not help at all

Comment: @MichaelCollins check answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve the stuck trackpad and brightness issue after waking from suspend.

1. create a new file: /etc/systemd/system/acpi-wake-andy.service

```
[Unit]
Description=ACPI Wake Service
 
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo RP05 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup"
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Enable this serviece

```
sudo systemctl start acpi-wake-andy.service
sudo systemctl enable acpi-wake-andy.service
sudo systemctl status acpi-wake-andy.service # check status
```

3. create a new file: /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-s2idle.conf

```
options nvidia NVreg_EnableS0ixPowerManagement=1
NVreg_S0ixPowerManagementVideoMemoryThreshold=10000
```

4. Check status `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` output

```
[s2idle] deep // Youre done reboot and test it worked
s2idle [deep] // Go to Step 5
```

5. (Only if the above command output: `s2idle [deep]`) edit  /etc/default/grub

- add mem_sleep_default=s2idle to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=s2idle"
```

- run `sudo update-grub`
- reboot, youre done test changes

Unfortunately i don't know why this works, im following those who have more experience than me who managed to get it working. Strongly recommend you check out [1] and [2] of the resources for more information..

resources:

- [1] https://insider.razer.com/index.php?threads/blade-15-mid-2021-rz09-0409-trackpad-not-working-on-resume.78555/page-2#post-815701
- [2] https://abarry.org/ubuntu-on-razer-blade-15-2022-advanced/
- [3] https://devnull.land/laptop-s2idle-to-deep