# Cannot change brightness Ubuntu 22.10, Razer Blade 15 2021 Advanced

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness, 22.10

I have scoured the internet, but have not found a solution that works. I downloaded ubuntu for a machine learning workload. However, I am unable to get my brightness controls to work properly. The function keys on the keyboard will change the slider, and I can manually change the slider, but it does not change the brightness level. I cannot even change it using xrandr. I am using kernel 6.2.8, and nvidia-driver-515. (I tried 525, it did not work either.) Any help is appreciated; my eyes are burning.

Ok, some updates after investigation:
When the function keys or slider tries to change the brightness, it changes the value in /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight/brightness file.
However, I can manually change the brightness by changing the value in the /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness file. It seems the discrepancy is basically getting the gui/function keys to change the value in the nvidia_0/brightness file, not the nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight/brightness file.
I am not sure on how to do that.

Comment: From what I have seen over the last few years, most Razer notebooks cannot have their brightness levels changed without a very specific utility that works only in Windows. If you have an OLED display, [this ICC profile *may* help](https://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness), but there is no guarantee. Do note that `xrandr` will not work if you're using a Wayland session, which is default for 22.10 

Comment: I was able to use this command to change the brightness to 50%: sudo su -c "echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness" However, this is tedious, and was hoping that I could find a way to link the gui slider and function buttons to it

Comment: One option would be to use an `inotify` watcher that updates the correct value when the wrong setting is updated 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a fix. I will document it here for future reference in case I need to rebuild my machine, or if someone else has this issue.

1. Create the following script: (I called it `/home/user/brightness.sh`)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   path=/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight
   inotifywait -q -m -e close_write $path |
   while read -r event; do        
       actual_brightness=$(cat $path/brightness)        
       scaled_brightness=$(echo "scale=0; (($actual_brightness - 5) * 99) / (255 - 5) + 1" | bc)        
       echo "Actual brightness: $actual_brightness, scaled brightness: $scaled_brightness"        
       echo $scaled_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness || echo "Failed to write brightness: $?"
   done
   ```
2. Allow this script to run with `sudo` and not require a password. This is fairly simple to do; use this site as a reference: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-running-sudo-command-without-a-password/. Or just ask chatgpt.
3. Add this script to the startup applications as a command. Ex: add the command:

   ```
   sudo /bin/bash /home/user/brightness.sh
   ```

   to run at startup.

I also had an issue with the trackpad not working after waking the machine back up from suspend. I fixed this by following the directions here: [Razer Blade 15 Errors on new ubuntu 22 installation ACPI BIOS Error (bug) + trackpad not working after suspending](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418408/razer-blade-15-errors-on-new-ubuntu-22-installation-acpi-bios-error-bug-trac)